# Ensure HTML iframe doesn't become taller than square

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an iframe that I want to allow to be as wide as the display requires. I have it inside of a `section`, and have the following in a `sass` file:

```
iframe
    max-width: 100%
```

where the real width, otherwise is controlled by the `section`. Now, on very narrow displays, like a smartphone, this works fine. However, the height of the `iframe` goes crazy in this case. Is there a way to ensure that the height of the object cannot get become larger than it's width? That is, is there a way to access what `100%` width actually is? I wish I could do something like this

```
iframe
    max-width: 100%
    max-height: max-width
```

**Edit:**

Please see here for a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptzyjmb1/5/

Notice how the first embedded object is wider than square. The second is about square. and the last is taller than square. I just want some option for `max-height` that will result in the third object (the "tall" video) to be square. That is, I want to be able to set the width to whatever I (or the display) would like, and the height will not be allowed to exceed that value.

I do not want to enforce that `height = width`, just that `height <= width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vh and vw attributes (view-height and view-width):

```
iframe {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vw;
}
```

If, as @Anonymous pointed out, the iframe is the child of some parent element that is not 100vw across, you can just use the div's width as the width of the iframe:

```
div {
    width: 50%
}
div iframe {
    max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 50vw;
```

If the width of the parent div is constantly changing, there is probably some JS being used. If the width of the parent element is represented in a variable, as it should be, then JQuery can sort out the problem, as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {$("div iframe").css("max-width",String(divwidth)+"vw");, 10)
```

Comment: While this worked for my purposes, it's not a solid fix, since if the `div` or `section` containing the `iframe` itself has some `maxwidth < 100vw`, then objects within that `section` will have `100% < 100vw`, since `vw` is absolute, while `%` is relative to the containing `section` or `div`

Comment: @Anonymous I edited the answer to provide a solution, thanks for pointing that out.